# Blank spaces in regular expression

Tags: java, regex, validation

I use this regular to validate many of the input fields of my java web app:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

But i need to modify it, because i have a couple of fields that need to allow blank spaces(for example: Address).

How can i modify it to allow blank spaces(**if possible not at the start**).

I think i need to use some scape character like `\`

I tried a few different combinations but none of them worked. Can somebody help me with this regex?

Comment: I did it: This is the pattern i used: `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$)?` At the end i use ? when the fields needs to be optional.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

It adds two things: first, you're guaranteed not to have a space at the beginning, while allowing characters you need. Afterwards, letters `a-z` and `A-Z` are allowed, as well as all digits and spaces (there's a space at the end of my regex).

Comment: This allows _any_ char (other than a space) as the first char, (e.g. any of these: `@&^$@*&^$#)(@#*$`) Probably not what you want!

Comment: @ridgerunner: you're correct; I updated my answer. I'd say this is the most readable version for use

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use only a whitespace, you can do:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`

If you want to include *tabs* `\t`, *new-line* `\n` `\r\n` characters, you can do:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$`

Also, as you asked, if you don't want the whitespace to be **at the begining**:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`. This should work. First atom ensures that there must be at least one character at beginning.

Comment: the first `+` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Oskar Yep. You are right. So the right one is `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`. I think darioo's regex is more compact.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$ that is, add a space in it

Comment: for to start with a character try like this ^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$

Answer (score 1):

This regex dont allow spaces at the end of string, one downside it accepts underscore character also.

```
^(\w+ )+\w+|\w+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: I assume that any input with a length of at least one character is valid. The previously mentioned answers does not take that into account.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"
```

If you want to allow all whitespace characters, replace the space by "\s"