# Regex pattern to allow space

Tags: java, android, regex

I have one regex which allows one Upper case, one Lower case, 8-16 characters and Most **special characters including space**. I want add allow space in the regex.

**I have tried :**

1. [Blank spaces in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753142/blank-spaces-in-regular-expression)
2. [Regex to allow alphanumeric, spaces, some special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721084/regex-to-allow-alphanumeric-spaces-some-special-characters)
3. [Java space and newline regex for split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848751/java-space-and-newline-regex-for-split)

**My regex is as follow :**

```
(?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~\|])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~\|]]*$
```

I just want to add space in this. I have tried **`\s`** and **`[ ]?`** but nothing works.

I have checked the `regex` on https://regex101.com/

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words

Comment: @Goku nothing is working for me i have added this type of space and checked on given site.. but not working

Comment: have u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102944/8112541

Comment: @Goku not working (?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~\|])([\w ]+)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z\w\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~\|]*$

Comment: Hi @Annie I think your problem is "(?!.*\s)" which translates to "no whitespaces" and includes spaces. But I cannot say for sure because I still don't get exactly what you try to accomplish and don't have a test string that works.

Just one tip: you can save your regex incl. example input at regex101.com and share it via link.

Comment: @Johannes she wants a password with one upper case, one lower case, one special character with space.. i.e. "Annie123  " or "Annie222!" these wil be valid one.. there have to b one special character and that character can be white space

Comment: @JohannesStadler thanks that worked for me.. please post as an answer for future visitors.. i will accept

Answer (score 2):

Probably there will be mistake in grouping.

As far as I have used RegEx, [ ] or \s will support the single space

Comment: Yes I will test and I will try to get it fixed, But if you send me a test string based on what you are testing, then that would be easier for me to analyze.